# How to expire cache in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I have a web page that gets cached in this way.

```
<% cache(params[:page]) do %>
  #Content
<% end %>
```

How can I expire cache now?

Comment: Have a look at [expire_fragment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, it's really important to tell us what you've tried. Failing to do that makes us think you haven't tried and just immediately asked, looking like you want us to write code for you. That's not a popular thing on SO, and quickly leads to down votes and questions being closed. Please see "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users to get an idea of the expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Rails.cache.delete(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ActiveSupport::Cache::Store, you should be able to do

```
<% cache(key, :expires_in => 1.hour) do %>
   <!-- content -->
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called fragment caching, according to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment) you can expire fragment by simply putting this code at your controller:

```
ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(params[:page], options = nil)
```